# ElasticSearch sort/score by deeply nested

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I've the following kind of documents in my index but can not find a way to sort that properly because of the deep nesting aspect.

Document example:

```
{
  "metadatas": [{
    "name": "name",
    "timeValidity": [{
      "since": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "until": "2100-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "value_s": "Some random name"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "riskRatio",
    "variants": [{
      "value": "3Y",
      "timeValidity": [{
        "since": "2017-11-17T23:59:59.999Z",
        "until": "2017-12-01T23:59:59.998Z",
        "value_f": 0.6931
      }, {
        "since": "2017-12-01T23:59:59.999Z",
        "until": "2018-03-01T23:59:59.999Z",
        "value_f": 0.7215
      }, {
        "since": "2018-04-12T00:00:00.000Z",
        "until": "2018-04-16T23:59:59.999Z",
        "value_f": 0.6849
      }]
    }]
  }]
}
```

I wish to sort or boost at match time so that I can get documents ordered by `metadatas.variants.timeValidity.value_f` (asc/desc) with the constrain that `metadata.name=riskRatio` and that within that nested document `metadata.variants.value=3Y` and that within that nested document `metadata.variants.timeValidity.since <= SOME_DATE` and `metadata.variants.timeValidity.until >= SOME_DATE`

Filtering results goes fine. My problem resides in the sorting side of things.

`script_score` seems to require specifying an access key which is not possible as I don't know the position within the arrays. `sort` doesn't let me filter range on two properties hence it's a dead end too. So my last failed attempt was to go from bottom to top like so:

```
{
  "sort": [{
    "metadatas.variants.timeValidity.value_f": {
      "mode": "min",
      "order": "asc",
      "nested": {
        "path": "metadatas.variants.timeValidity",
        "filter": {
          "range": {
            "metadatas.variants.timeValidity.since": {
              "lte": "2018-01-21T23:59:59.999Z"
            },
            "metadatas.variants.timeValidity.until": { // forbidden !!
              "gte": "2018-01-21T23:59:59.999Z"
            }
          }
        },
        "nested": {
          "path": "metadatas.variants",
          "filter": {
            "match": {
              "metadatas.variants.value": "3Y"
            }
          },
          "nested": {
            "path": "metadatas",
            "filter": {
              "match": {
                "metadatas.name": "riskRatio"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }]
}
```

How can I properly sort? Sorting by boosting is ok too but is a dead end to me.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `explain:true` to the query is very helpful to debug and understand what is going on.

This gives you an additional `sort` key by hits showing the value it took.

To be able to query two ranges, what must be used is the `BooleanQuery` in the `filter` section of the sort. The final correct query is the following:

```
{
  "sort": [{
    "metadatas.variants.timeValidity.value_f": {
      "mode": "min",
      "order": "asc",
      "nested": {
        "path": "metadatas",
        "filter": {
          "match": {
            "metadatas.name": "riskRatio"
          }
        },
        "nested": {
          "path": "metadatas.variants",
          "filter": {
            "match": {
              "metadatas.variants.value": "3Y"
            }
          },
          "nested": {
            "path": "metadatas.variants.timeValidity",
            "filter": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [{
                  "range": {
                    "metadatas.variants.timeValidity.since": {
                      "lte": "2018-01-21T23:59:59.999Z"
                    }
                  }
                }, {
                  "range": {
                    "metadatas.variants.timeValidity.until": {
                      "gte": "2018-01-21T23:59:59.999Z"
                    }
                  }
                }]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }]
}
```